# Radiobutton value not set in edit mode in asp.net mvc 5 (vb)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In my code , for edit page gender value is not set

```
<label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(model) model.Sex, "M", New With {Key .checked = (If(Model.Sex = "M", True, False))}) Male
    </label>
    <label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(model) model.Sex, "F", New With {Key .checked = (If(Model.Sex = "F", True, False))}) Female
    </label>
```

////////////////////////////////////////
edited

```
Async Function Edit(ByVal id As Long?) As Task(Of ActionResult)
        If IsNothing(id) Then
            Return New HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        End If
        ViewBag.Title = "Employee Master View"
        Dim employeeMaster As EmployeeMaster = Await db.EmployeeMaster.FindAsync(id)
        ViewBag.task = "Edit"
        If IsNothing(employeeMaster) Then
            Return HttpNotFound()
        End If
        Return View("EmployeeMasterView", employeeMaster)
    End Function
```

In edit mode always female is checked...
What is the problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a radio button, `checked` or `checked="checked"` or `checked="false"` or `checked="anyThingAtAll"` do exactly the same thing, they set the `checked` attribute, although only the first 2 are valid html.

As the html is generated, the first radio button is selected, then the second one (and the first one is un-checked because only one can be selected)

Do not set the value of the `checked` attribute when using the html helpers. Remove it from both. Your strongly binding to a model property so the helpers use the value of the property to determine which radio button to set the `checked` attribute. If the value if propery `Sex"` is `"M"`, then the first button will be selected. If its `"F"`, then the second one will be. And if its neither, then no button will be selected.

Comment: Default it is a text box... radio button Html code is manually coded. I removed the condition and 'checked' .Still not worked

Comment: What do you mean manually code? And what do you mean its a text box? Your using `@Html.RadioButtonFor()` which generates radio buttons! Give me 5 minutes and I'll create a DotNetFiddle to prove it works

Comment: Yes, it is. But in my case it doesn't worked. the edited code is above

Comment: What does you edit have to do with anything? Check the value of `employeeMaster.Sex`. If its not working its because the value is not either `"M"` or "F"`

Comment: And you might want to review the code in your controller. No idea what your `SetViewBag()` method does but its passing property values of `employeeMaster` which could be `null` (Nothing) and throw an exception. In the next line you check if its `null` but by then its too late